# BB10 port from Android - Gridview Re-orders when bb10 action bar is enabled

Tags: android, blackberry-10

I have an android application which I am porting to BB10 and am running into an interesting issue with grid views on layout resizing.

The layout is fairly simple - just a Gridview along with several other components nested in a relative layout. When the activity starts up, the layout behaves just fine - all components are displayed properly, and the Gridview icons are in the expected locations.

But, when opening up the built in action bar for BB10, the gridview appears to completely invert itself after the layout resizes to fit the actionbar. Selecting one of the now inverted items in the gridview actually selects the element that SHOULD be there instead of the one that is now being displayed.

Has anyone else run into this issue/know of a reasonable work around for it?

The onCreate method is also very simple - it just calls the superclass' onCreate and sets the content view.

My layout is below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/home_root"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/banner_header"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:src="@drawable/header" />

    <GridView
        android:id="@+id/buttonGrid"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@id/banner_header"
        android:horizontalSpacing="2dip"
        android:numColumns="2"
        android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
        android:verticalSpacing="20dip" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/aboutImage"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:src="@drawable/info_gear" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/bookmarkImage"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/aboutImage"
        android:layout_below="@+id/banner_header"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:onClick="onClickBookmarkButton"
        android:src="@drawable/bookmarklist" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a couple more hours of tinkering I found that resetting the adapter to itself without making any changes to it fixes the issue.

```
((GridView)findViewById(R.id.buttonGrid)).setAdapter(adapter);
```